# How to get url of website call NPAPI Plugin?

Tags: c++, plugins, npapi, firebreath

I have a NPAPI Plugin. I want to know what website call my plugin, i want to my Plugin get url website and post to my Server. How can i use Plugin to get url website call Plugin? If i can then how to do it?
Thanks!

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

```
m_host->getDOMWindow()->getLocation()
```